# Random Field Query

Tags: visualforce, soql, controller

I have this on my controller.

```
private String userName;
userList = [SELECT Username, Question_1__c, Question_2__c, Question_3__c 
FROM User WHERE Username = :userName LIMIT 1];
```

What should I do to display 2 out of 3 question randomly on an output panel?

```
<apex:outputField value="{!userList[0].QUESTIONHERE123}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!userList[0].QUESTIONHERE123}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the random funtion in the Math class and create a method:

```
public Integer randomWithLimit(Integer upperLimit){
   Integer rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
   return Math.mod(rand,upperLimit);
}
```

I multiply it by 10 because I want a range between 0 and 9. Since you always have 3 questions I would have the upper limit to 3.

Also why do you have different fields for different questions? The rest of the code I imagine to be; you select all the questions from the database and store them in a list:

```
List<Questions__c> questions = [Select Question__c from Questions__c];
Integer removeAt = randomWithLimit(questions.size());
questions.remove(removeAt);
//Remove the 2 questions to the visualforce page
return questions;
```